# simulating a domain name with hostfile doesn't work as expected on IIS website

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have added a domain name in hostfile

127.0.0.1 mydomain.com

I created a website under IIS7 binding to mydomain.com and created a blank index.html in the website folder for test

But when I type in browser http://mydomain.com it shows the file for IIS default website. Instead I have to type http://mydomain.com/index.html to get the right page.

Same result for index.aspx file

Why ? What should I do ?

Comment: Does it happen to any other file or index.html only?

Comment: What if you replace 127.0.0.1 with your actual IP?

Comment: great it works you should put in answer so I can check it as good one :)

Comment: Maybe it's due to some bug though http://forums.iis.net/t/1176071.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was to replace 127.0.0.1 with actual IP of the server.